# How can I prove this probability equation?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Say we have:
$$ y = A(1+X)^n $$
where $ 'X' $ is a random variable that is normally distributed with a mean $ 'μ' $ and a standard deviation $ 'σ' $.
If the following statement is true, how can it be proved?
$$ E[A(1+X)^n] = A(1+μ)^n $$
EDIT: What would be the expected value of $'y'$?

Comment: Hi!, Kindly show your thoughts on the problem and what results you are allowed to use.

Comment: Why not try to work out the case $A=1,\,n=2$ in detail?

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the suggestion, that was indeed a simple way to prove an inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming also that A is a parameter,

using [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) you can prove that your statement is false. In fact

$$\mathbb{E}[1+X]^n \ge (1+\mathbb{E}[X])^n$$

this is valid in general, not only when $X$ is Normally distributed

---

Using @lulu's hint, setting $A=1,n=2$ you can have a counterexample being

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[1+X]^2 & =\mathbb{E}[1+2X+X^2]\\
& =1+2\mu+\sigma^2+\mu^2\\
& = (1+\mu)^2+\sigma^2>(1+\mu)^2
\end{align}$$

$\forall \sigma^2>0$